# Using Facebook graph in Chrome Extensions

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, authorization, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use Facebook graph in Chrome extensions, but I'm having trouble in using access token to have permissions. My extension folder has a background.html file with the this code:

```
function displayUser(user) {
       var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
       var greetingText = document.createTextNode('Greetings, ' + user.name + '.');
       userName.appendChild(greetingText);
    }

    var appID = "XXXXX";
    if (window.location.hash.length == 0) {
      var path = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?';
      var queryParams = ['client_id=' + appID,'redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html', 'response_type=token'];
      var query = queryParams.join('&');
      var url = path + query;
      window.open(url);
    } else {
      var accessToken = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      var path = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";

      var queryParams = [accessToken, 'callback=displayUser'];
      var query = queryParams.join('&');
      var url = path + query;

   // use jsonp to call the graph
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src = url;
       document.body.appendChild(script);        
     }
```

When I run the extension, it opens a new tab with the app authorization. When I accept it, it just says "Success" and the url of this tab is like this:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=AAABtoJwdQQgBAP8KK6QYmlQ1CJOSjQxWjXoa7qgUthF507BGPgLeWEplB87fZBpDZBZBd7CKoIWb4Fa3S2laBuZAUf795p1N3QZDZD&expires_in=5549

So now how can I use this access token in background.html and close that authorization tab?

Answer (score 1):

You should watch (in the extension code) for the tab changes with success url like this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onTabUpdated);
```

Then the handler function:

```
function onTabUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url && changeInfo.url.indexOf(SUCCESS_URL) == 0) {
     // extract access token from url
```

Extract function:

```
function accessTokenFromSuccessURL(url) {
var hashSplit = url.split('#');
if (hashSplit.length > 1) {
  var paramsArray = hashSplit[1].split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < paramsArray.length; i++) {
    var paramTuple = paramsArray[i].split('=');
    if (paramTuple.length > 1 && paramTuple[0] == 'access_token')
      return paramTuple[1];
  }
}
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Judging by `redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`, I'm assuming you're building a desktop or a client side app.

Try adding `var RedirectURI = window.location;`
And change the redirect URI in the queryParams array to `redirect_uri= RedirectURI`
If required, you can add http://localhost to the Site URL entry in https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Once the token is obtain, it is redirected to your previous page with the authorization token added as a hash which is automatically handled by the `else { }` block in your code.